# getting execution time of a Sequel query

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

It's easy to measure the time difference on the client, but to get the actual execution time on the database server, it looks like I might have to dig deep into the Postgres adapter.  Is there a better and more adapter-agnostic way to extract this information?

Comment: Might be more than you want, but can be useful: https://github.com/ankane/pghero

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to get the time programatically so I can record it elsewhere.  Eyeballing the execution time isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `logger` option to the initializer and it will print the query and the time spent

```
DB = Sequel.connect(database_uri, logger: Logger.new(STDOUT))
DB[:table].where(id: 1..1000)
```

It will print something like

```
I, [2018-04-25T22:20:52.692312 #2685]  INFO -- : (0.398486s) SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE (("id" >= 1) AND ("id" <= 1000))
```

Comment: You can also override Database#log_duration if you want to get the timing information without having to parse it out of the log output. You do have to have a logger setup though, even if it doesn't do anything, otherwise Sequel doesn't calculate the timing.